# AVQueuePlayer SeekToTime

Tags: avqueueplayer, seektotime

```
[queuePlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMake(time,1)];
```

While I take `seekToTime`, the audio does replay, not seek to the time.
How to create `CMTime` para or you can tell me how to do all.

Answer (score -1):

**Please try below code:**

```
UISlider *s = (UISlider*)sender;
[appDelegate.queuePlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(s.value, queuePlayer.currentTime.timescale)];
```

first para is progress (0-1.0)
second para like this '`queuePlayer.currentTime.timescale`'

Comment: first para is seconds ,